# tableview how to append to empty array checked cells?

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkBtn     : UIButton!


    @IBAction func selectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if checkBtn.isSelected == false {
            checkBtn.isSelected = true
        } else {
            checkBtn.isSelected = false
        }
    }
}
```

I have a cell class. But the IBACtion does not work.

I also make a ViewController like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)   -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "exampleCell") as! Cell

    if cell.checkBtn.isSelected == true {
            anEmptyArray.append(myTableViewData[indexPath.row])
        } else {

        }

}
```

How I can get selected cells?

Comment: An extra array is a bad approach. Maintain the `selected` state in the data model. By the way you can replace the entire `if - else` expression in `selectButton` with `sender.isSelected.toggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following table view delegate method, below is the code.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
     anEmptyArray.append(myTableViewData[indexPath.row])
}
```

Also make sure you have following line of code in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```swift
 tableView.delegate = self
```

With this approach you have to just select the cell. That's all.

**Another Approach**

You need to create new delegate.

```swift
protocol TableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
   func didSelect(cell: YourTableViewCell) // Don't need to define just declare.
}
```

Now create a delegate instance in `UITableViewCell` class, and call method inside button action.

```swift
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkBtn     : UIButton!
    weak var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate? // Instance of Delegate protocol


    @IBAction func selectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if checkBtn.isSelected == false {
            checkBtn.isSelected = true
        } else {
            checkBtn.isSelected = false
        }
        
        self.delegate?.didSelect(cell: self) // triggering the delegate method. 
    }
}
```

Now which code will be trigger? We need to define that. Go to your UITableViewController, and extend that class, for example

```swift
extension YourTableViewController: TableViewCellDelegate {
     func didSelect(cell: YourTableViewCell) {
       // Now you have the cell, and you can get the indexPath of this cell
         if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            // Now you have indexPath and you know the drill.
             

            // If you want to remove that cell delete that value from array and reload tableView.
            
            myTableViewData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.reloadData()

            
         }
     }
}
```

Don't forget making the cell delegate of YourTableViewController like below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)   -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "exampleCell") as! YourTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self

}
```

Comment: Wow It is easy. Thank you. But I also want to remove if cell is unselected. how?

Comment: Thanks. But I apologize. I want remove from emptyArray what I appended. Exapmle: emptyarray = [] when I select three cells, emptyArray = [1,2,3]. And I deselect a cell(2). emptyArray = [1,3]